# Unexpected boolean result with vector size and -1

Tags: c++, c++11

In the test

```
bool test = -1 > vec.size();
```

where vec is a non-empty vector, the value of test is true.
Why? How would this be investigated?

```
  bool test0 = -1 > 10; // false
  // vec.size() = 10
  bool test1 = -1 > vec.size();  // true
  bool test2 = 0 > vec.size();   // false
  bool test3 = 1 > vec.size();   // false
  bool test4 = 11 >= vec.size(); // true
```

Comment: `size()` returns an unsigned integer. You can't compare signed and unsigned integers directly. `-1` is being implicitly converted to an unsigned integer type, which can't represent the value `-1` correctly.

Comment: *How would this be investigated?* This particular issue is easily caught if you enable your compiler warnings.

Comment: fwiw, since C++20 there is [`std::ssize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) (non-member) which returns a signed value